# magento 2.4.5 huge category reindex catalogsearch_fulltext is very slow

Tags: magento2, category-products, catalogsearch-fulltext

I have more than 100000+ products and 20 store views, one of the category has 60000+ products, when I reindex catalogsearch_fulltext, It took more than 20 hours, and still doesn't finish.

and the category with 60000+ products also couldn't access got 500 error.

I googled many articles to try to figure out solution, but all doesn't work for me.

my server is 16v CPU, 128G RAM, Mariadb 10.4, Nginx + PHP8.1

```
skip-name-resolve=1

table_open_cache = 2000

table_definition_cache = -1

performance_schema=ON

join_buffer_size = 8M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 30G

innodb_log_file_size = 16M

tmp_table_size = 25G

max_heap_table_size = 25G

innodb_log_file_size = 3G

innodb_io_capacity=600

read_rnd_buffer_size=128K

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16

innodb_lru_scan_depth=100

log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain

slow_query_log=ON
```

I also changed memory_limint to 8G.
anyone can help me to solve it? it's been a long time, I've tried all suggestions on google.

Comment: What is your version of MySql/MariaDB?

Comment: Mariadb 10.4 @panosdotk

Comment: According to Magento documentation: Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 takes more time compared to other MariaDB or MySQL versions. To speed up reindexing, we recommend setting these MariaDB configuration parameters: `optimizer_switch=‘rowid_filter=off’` and `optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1`. This will speed up reindex procedure

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: When you are ready to improve performance, please post info requested on Mar 14, 2023 for Suggestions to apply to your Global Variables to help your instance.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the memory limit for PHP and adjust the max_execution_time parameter to allow more time for the indexer to complete

Comment: I 've increased memory_limint to 8G and max_execution_time = 18000

Comment: set max_execution_time=72000

Comment: thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

According to Magento Documentation

*Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 takes more time compared to other MariaDB or MySQL versions. To speed up reindexing, we recommend setting these MariaDB configuration parameters:*

`optimizer_switch=‘rowid_filter=off’`

`optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1`

You can find it at the end of page [General MySQL guidelines](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/database-server/mysql.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

according to Adobe in this documentation:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/catalog/catalog-flat.html?lang=en
Use of a flat catalog is no longer recommended as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're issue experiencing reindexing and accessing a large category. Here are solutions that you can try:

1. Split up the category: If a single category has 60000+ products, it
   might be worth considering splitting it up into smaller
   subcategories. This can help with both indexing and browsing
   performance.
2. Upgrade your hardware: If your server is underpowered, it might
   struggle with indexing and serving pages for a large store. Consider
   upgrading to a more powerful server or using a cloud hosting
   solution.
3. Optimize your database: Large databases can also cause performance
   issues. Consider optimizing your database and removing any
   unnecessary data. You can use tools like MySQLTuner or Percona
   Toolkit to help with this.
4. Enable flat catalog: Enabling flat catalog can help with performance
   by reducing the number of database queries needed to fetch product
   data. You can do this by going to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend` and setting `"Use Flat Catalog Category"` and `"Use Flat Catalog Product"` to `"Yes"`.
5. Use Elasticsearch instead of MySQL for catalog search: Elasticsearch
   is a powerful search engine that can handle large volumes of data
   more efficiently than MySQL. Consider integrating Elasticsearch into
   your store for faster and more accurate search results.
6. Use a third-party indexing solution: There are third-party solutions
   available that can help with indexing large Magento stores. These
   solutions typically use more advanced indexing algorithms and can be
   faster and more reliable than Magento's built-in indexing.
7. Consider upgrading to Magento 2: Magento 2 is a more modern and
   scalable platform that can handle large stores more efficiently than
   Magento 1. If you're still using Magento 1, it might be worth
   considering upgrading to Magento 2.

Comment: what is third-party indexing solution?

Comment: If you go to over Google and search reindex third party module, you will get various vendor modules like Amasty, mirasvit etc...

Answer (score 0):

I set

```
System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend and setting "Use Flat Catalog Category" and "Use Flat Catalog Product" to "Yes".
and optimizer_switch=‘rowid_filter=off’
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
```

I also used elasticsearch 7
but when I reindex catalogsearch_fulltext, It still take more than 24 hours and doesn't finish.